# Is there any Apache Axis WSDL2Java jar file for Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, wsdl2java

Is there any separate org.apache.axis.wsdl2java jar file for Eclipse Indigo version because its not worked in indigo version shows error like:

**The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in "org.apache.axis.wsdl2java.eclipse" was unable to instantiate class "org.apache.axis.wsdl2java.eclipse.wizards.WebReferenceImportWizard".
org/eclipse/core/internal/utils/Assert**

But that jar file is worked in Eclipse sdk 2.1 version, so how can i do conversion?

Thanks,
@nag.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Axis2 in the past but now I only use CXF. Since CXF works for me and no one answered yet, let me suggest you give it a try at the CXF wsdl2java plugin. It is easy to setup in a maven pom.xml project

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Reference http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html